# Python Else condition not working for random.randint

Tags: python

Even when value of r is 6,7,8,9,10. player2 is never returned as output

```
import random
def choose_first():                                    
    r = random.randint(0,10)
    if r == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 :
        return ('player1')
    else:
        return ('player2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. When you say - `if r == 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 :`, it directly means `if True :` because you have provided numbers as condition directly which will be interpreted as `True`

You should do it like following -

```
import random
def choose_first():                                    
    r = random.randint(0,10)
    if r == 0 or r == 1 or r == 2 or r == 3 or r == 4 or r == 5 :
        return ('player1')
    else:
        return ('player2')
```

Better way, you could do it in the following manner

```
import random
def choose_first():                                    
    r = random.randint(0,10)
    if r in [1,2,3,4,5] :
        return ('player1')
    else:
        return ('player2')
```